# Seeking a fairy tale about a monster named "Rope-Nose"

Tags: story-identification, fairy-tales

When I was young, around 1980, my father read me a story about a monster named "Rope-Nose," who had (unsurprisingly) a long nose that was flexible like a rope.  I'm not sure if it was an authentic Slavic fairy tale or something written by a modern author in the same style.

Rope-Nose had taken to killing and eating villagers, and a clever fellow was sent out to deal with the problem.  The clever man approached the monster and convinced him that he wanted to paint his picture.  First, he got Rope-Nose to sit on a horse, to make him look more majestic; then he convinced the monster to let his long nose be tied to a tree branch overhead, so it wouldn't be obstructing his face.

You probably see where this is going, but Rope-Nose, being a fairy tale ogre, did not.  The clever fellow spooks the horse, which runs off, leaving Rope-Nose dangling helplessly in space.  At that point, the tsar's troops are called in to shoot him with their cannons, ending the threat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We think its (or is in) 
Mishka-Pishka-and-Fishka-Galician-Tales-Eric-Kimmel-1976
see below for how...ignore bit about Wade Wellman.

(Not directly the story you're looking for but it might suggest the area its from. The horror story The Desrick Up On Yando, by Manley Wade Wellman which draws on American folk myth, mentions the 'rope-nose' as one of the creatures that protects the witch's hut or Desrick.  So perhaps you're looking for a book of American folk tales?)

Have dug further - typing Ropenose into Googlebooks gives me a copy of the Horn Magazine vol 52-53 whose page 497 refences a folktale called Ropenose about a photographer who bests a brigand whose nose is so long he ties it around his waist. The tale comes from Galica (partly poland, partly Russia) unfortunately I can't access page 496 via googlebooks to get the name of the story collection. Am seeing how else to go.

And with thanks to Valorum (see comments) we have a title for a collection of Galican folk tales!  [Sorry about the Wellman which is a red-herring, that rope-nose being a sort of dwarf mammoth].

Comment: Can you provide a quote?

Comment: Ahem; http://www.worldcat.org/title/mishka-pishka-fishka-and-other-galician-tales/oclc/1975299

Comment: You'll want to edit the title of the collection into your answer :-)

Comment: There are some panels and pages from the book here. https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Mishka-Pishka-and-Fishka-Galician-Tales-Eric-Kimmel-1976-DJ-/371848680607?epid=1605442&hash=item5693e8949f%3Ag%3AO5AAAMXQUmFSfFYT&_trkparms=pageci%253A8c7758ad-9f6e-11e7-9b80-74dbd1806b9b%257Cparentrq%253Aa8aa368315e0aa465393d588ffd00a03%257Ciid%253A14 - It mentions that Ropenose is a cannibal in the frontispiece

Comment: This one mentions a photographer trying to trick Ropenose; https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/YqIAAMXQWzNSfFYn/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: The entire book is available online at https://archive.org/details/mishkapishkafish00kimm (although registration is required, which I haven't previously experienced at the Internet Archive).